# How can I check in a pandas dataframe for a different values in different columns at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say we have a pandas.df with a bunch of columns filled with numbers between 0 and 1, like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4],
                   'col2':[0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5],
                   'col3':[0.3,0.4,0.1,0.2]})
```

and then, a list of numbers I want to check if they exist in the dataframe, for example

```
vals = [0.1,0.2,0.3]
```

Where the first value should be checked in `col1`, the second value in `col2` and so on.

Is there a way to check the list of values against each column easily?

If it's one column we want to check, the answer is easy, we can just do

```py
df.loc[df['col1'] == vals[0]]
```

and that returns the first row

|col1|  col2|  col3|
|-|-|-|
|0.1 |  0.2   |0.3|
which matches the requirements

The obvious next step would be doing something like:

```py
df.loc[df['col1'] == vals[0] & df['col2'] == vals[1] & df['col3'] == vals[2]]
```

which doesn't work because you need the `.any()` function to avoid it being a series (with ambiguous truth value. Adding `.any()`

```py
df[(df['col1'] == vals[0]).any() and (df['col2'] == vals[1]).any() and (df['col3'] == vals[2]).any()]
```

doesn't solve the problem, as it will return `KeyError: True`

So, is there a way to check different values in different columns (they should appear in the same row)?

PS: It would be best if it does not need to manually write the columns as in `df.loc[df['col1'] == vals[0]]`, the dataframe I'm using has more than 20 columns and it would be really annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = df[df[:]== vals].dropna()
```

gives:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.1   0.2   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `len(vals) == len(df.columns)`, you can use:

```
df[df.eq(vals).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3
0   0.1   0.2   0.3
```

Using [`df.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`Series.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) (or [`Series.any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) if any `True` is ok).